# Library working when called from Console app but not from NUnit test

Tags: c#, nunit, .net-standard, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to evaluate a workflow library for a project I'm working on. The lib can be found at [github workflow-core](https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core).

To start things up I was trying to build a simple workflow, that just writes some text to a file. The curious thing is, that the workflow works fine, when called from a console application project. But when I use the same code in an NUnit test and run it, it doesn't write anything to the file.

I'm a little lost here and don't even know which details are import for you guys to know to help me figure this out, but maybe this might be relevant?

- The workflow-core library is build on .NET standard 2.0
- The NUnit project and the console project both use .NET Framework 4.7.2
- The workflow-core lib uses all kinds of Tasks (as in Task Parallel Library) stuff
- The workflow-core lib is build with dependency injection using the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` library

And here is the relevant code:
First the workflow class:

```
public class HelloWorldWorkflow : IWorkflow
{
    public string Id => nameof(HelloWorldWorkflow);
    public int Version => 1;
    public void Build(IWorkflowBuilder<object> builder)
    {
        builder.StartWith((context) =>
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Test\test.txt", "Test line worked!");
            return ExecutionResult.Next();
        });
    }
}
```

The calling code from the console app (working):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddLogging((config) => config.AddConsole());
        serviceCollection.AddWorkflow();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<LogStep>();

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        var host = serviceProvider.GetService<IWorkflowHost>();
        host.RegisterWorkflow<HelloWorldWorkflow>();

        host.Start();

        host.StartWorkflow(nameof(HelloWorldWorkflow));

        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadLine();

        host.Stop();
    }
}
```

And the code from my test project (not working):

```
[TestFixture]
public class ExplorationTests
{
    private ServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private IWorkflowHost _host;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        serviceCollection.AddLogging((config) => config.AddConsole());
        serviceCollection.AddWorkflow();

        serviceCollection.AddTransient<LogStep>();
        serviceCollection.AddTransient<HelloWorldWorkflow>();

        _serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

        _host = _serviceProvider.GetService<IWorkflowHost>();
        _host.RegisterWorkflow<HelloWorldWorkflow>();

        _host.Start();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        _host.StartWorkflow(nameof(HelloWorldWorkflow));

    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        _host.Stop();
    }
}
```

I'd be glad for any clues on how to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execution of workflows is asynchronous, therefore you have to wait for some kind of event to occur which signals the completion.
Otherwise your test teardown will kill the host before the workflow has the chance to do anything.

This answer's first version contained:

Adding `.Wait()` or one of its overloadings (which allow to specify a maximum duration to wait) to the result of `StartWorkflow` to block the test until the workflow has completed.

Unfortunately that's wrong as `StartWorkflow` returns a `Task` yielding only the ID of the workflow instance. When this task is resolved your workflow probably hasn't done anything meaningful.

There is a feature request on GitHub asking for the desired feature: [Wait for workflow to finish](https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core/issues/162)

Until that request is resolved, you may help yourself by creating a `ManualResetEvent` or maybe `AutoResetEvent` and putting it somewhere your final workflow step can access and call `.Set()` on it. Your test should wait for that by calling `.WaitOne()` on it (this is blocking).

Another event which might be sufficient (but inefficient) is just having waited a long enough duration: `Thread.Sleep(2000)` waits two seconds. Please be aware that even after that it's possible that your workflow has not completed due to the asynchronous nature of the workflow executor.

Comment: Thx man, that pointed me in the right direction. While waiting for the task itself did't help, sleeping the thread for 5 seconds did. I have to dig a little deeper in the lib to see if there's a way to wait for a specific workflow in particular.

Comment: You are right. After further research on that library I learned that `StartWorkflow` will return a task calculating only the ID of the workflow instance. I will edit my answer according to that. There is a dedicated issue on GitHub about waiting for finishing a workflow: https://github.com/danielgerlag/workflow-core/issues/162

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by making 'var serviceCollection' as class member of ExplorationTests. Otherwise code looks ok.

Comment: Unfortunately that did't help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your test starts a task running in the host and then exits without waiting for completion. The one time teardown would then run immediately and stop the host.

You should not be ending the test without waiting for the task to complete.